# Access map inside a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, maps

I have a data structure that is:

```
vector<pair<map<unsigned char, unsigned char>,unsigned short>>
```

And i am trying to access the map and print its first and second elements, but am having trouble accessing it properly.

Here is what i have so far:

```
auto dataSetMapIt = vLpatDataSet[i].first.begin();
fwrite(&dataSetMapIt->first, sizeof(dataSetMapIt->first), 1, filePtr);
fwrite(&dataSetMapIt->second, sizeof(dataSetMapIt->second), 1, filePtr);
```

Can anyone see what im doing wrong for it to not be accessing the map values properly?

Comment: Please add more details. Expand on *but am having trouble accessing it properly* Are you seeing compile time errors, run time errors? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are no compile or run time errors, it is simply not iterating properly, thus not printing the proper values.

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se with the code you've shown.

Comment: @CodyPritchard, if it is not iterating properly, it is a run time error. Without an MCVE, it's hard to suggest anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just print the first key/value pair of each map in vector.

And maybe I think you want to print all pairs in every map in vector.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vLpatDataSet.size(); ++i)
{
    const map < unsigned char, unsigned char>& mapInVector = vLpatDataSet[i].first;
    for (auto keyValuePair : mapInVector)
    {
        fwrite(&keyValuePair.first, sizeof(keyValuePair.first), 1, filePtr);
        fwrite(&keyValuePair.second, sizeof(keyValuePair.second), 1, filePtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we solved it later on.

There was a buffer variable we were forgetting to clear when pushing into the vector, thus explains why we and no one else could see anything wrong with the logic. 

Thanks